# Overriding multiple times in different subclasses problem

Tags: c#, overriding

When using this line of code i get the error message called "Indentifier expected, on the line with taskArray[i] = animalList[i].((Animal)animalObj).ToString(); at the "." before ((Animal). This method is supposed to use ToString method depending on what the user has input since there are multiple subclasses that can be called. Animal: Mammal and animal : Insect is what i currently have and i need to be able to use a ToString depending on what i send inside the Animal animalObj.

Just using .ToString() works just fine and idk if there is any other way to let the program know which ToString method i want it to call.

```
    public string ListToStringArray(int x, Animal animalObj)
    {
        string[] taskArray = new string[Count];// makes another array the size of the list

        for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++) //does a loop equal to the amonut of items in the list
        {
            taskArray[i] = animalList[i].((Animal)animalObj).ToString(); //puts the values inside the list into the array 

        }
        return taskArray[x]; //returns the array number which the method calls 
    }
```

Comment: What is `animalList`?

Comment: Sorry, i should have posted that, private List<Animal> animalList = new List<Animal>();

Comment: @adde09: then you just need `taskArray[i] = animalList[i].ToString()`. No cast is necessary if you get already an `Animal`. But since you want to call `ToString`(which exists already in Object) you could always call it, no matter if you used an `ArrayList` or `List<Object>` or `List<Animal>`.

Comment: Yes, but i have multiple ToString() methods inside the project. How would the program know which one to use?

Comment: @adde09: you have an `Animal`, so it will use the one that is overridden in `Animal`. If it wasn't overridden it will use the one that comes next up the inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: He will determine which method has to be used according to the type of the current object if it's an animal it'll use from animal if it's insect it'll use insect...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the syntax is incorrect, you want to use:

```
taskArray[i] = animalList[i].ToString();
```

> Yes, but i have multiple `ToString()` methods inside the project. How
>   would the program know which one to use?

You have commented that `animalList` is a `List<Animal>`. So this will call the `ToString` that is overridden in the actual class in this list. If you for example have these animals:

```
abstract class Animal
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "I'm just an animal, no idea what i am actually";
    }
}

class Lion : Animal
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "ROAR!!!";
    }
}
class Giraffe : Animal
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "[Donno what noise a giraffe makes]";
    }
}

class Meerkat: Animal
{
    // no ToString
}
```

Then following code

```
var animalsList = new List<Animal> {new Lion(), new Giraffe(), new Meerkat()};
animalsList.ForEach(a => Console.WriteLine(a.ToString()));
```

outputs

```
ROAR!!!
[Donno what noise a giraffe makes]
I'm just an animal, no idea what i am actually
```

You see that always the `ToString` which is overridden is called even if the list is declared as `List<Animal>`. That's how inheritance works in C#.

If you don't override it you get the one from [`System.Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2) which just returns the fully qualified name of the object's type.

Answer (score 0):

```
animalList[i].((Animal)animalObj).ToString();
```

Is invalid syntax, after animalList[i]. you can only put method or field or property. Like:

```
animalList[i].ToString();
```

or:

```
animalList[i].Name;
```

and so on.

Comment: Yes, but how else would i tell the program which ToString i want it to use?

Comment: There can be only one parameterless ToString() method in Animal class, so you will always use the same method.

Comment: Okay, so how would i change the ToString() Method inside the Animal class from e.g Cat?

Comment: If your animal[i] is actually Cat and ToString() is overriden in Cat then Cat's ToString will be called. If your animal is Animal then Animal's ToString() will be called. So if you have List<Animal>, but some of these Animals are Cats then for these Cats their ToString method will be called.

Comment: The only case you need to cast is when you  use new keyword in method declaration (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/knowing-when-to-use-override-and-new-keywords)